# ScrollArea how scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xico2k-react-scroll-area

I have a problem, how can I scroll to the bottom?
I found method like `goToBottom(duration = 400);` but how can I use it?

My code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import ScrollArea  from 'xico2k-react-scroll-area';

export default function Chat() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ScrollArea>
                [... some long div]
            </ScrollArea>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are not much of documentation so i have checked the source code of their [demo](https://github.com/xiCO2k/react-scroll-area/blob/master/src/demo/App.js) and it looks like you can use goToBottom function as follows:

import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import ScrollArea  from 'xico2k-react-scroll-area';

```
export default function Chat() {

 goToBottom() {
    this.refs.scroll.goToBottom(your_duration);
 }

 return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <ScrollArea>
            [... some long div]
        </ScrollArea>
    </React.Fragment>
 );
}
```